# Dragging a window to a space doesn't work the first time

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

In Mountain Lion (at least, maybe elsewhere too):

1. Enter Mission Control to see all windows, and all spaces.
2. Drag a window or a stack of windows to a space

For me, the first attempt at this fails reliably; the space doesn't get darkened focus appearance, window springs back to original location on mouseup:

The second attempt succeeds reliably; space darkens, window moves on mouseup:

Happens with all applications, on a very fresh install of Mountain Lion, with no UI hack utilities installed, etc. Very annoying at start of workday when trying to place apps in spaces. Is this a bug or some sort of feature I am not aware of?

**Update**: After upgrade to 10.8.2, this problem is resolved.

Comment: That’s strange… I don’t have this problem on my two computers.

Comment: You get the focus behavior 100% of the time, when moving windows? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I do. There was no problem in either Lion or Mountain Lion.

Comment: I could also reproduce the bug in 10.8.1, but it was fixed by the 10.8.2 upgrade. Can you post it as an answer so this question won't get bumped up later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed: the mountain lion 10.8.2 update resolves this problem.

Comment: Broken again in 10.8.4 - at least for me.

Comment: Be sure you're not trying to move a window to the space it's already in, or trying to move a window like iTunes, which is not a normal window, but which lives on all spaces by default. 10.8.4 seems to be working OK for me.